# Highlight menu item in ActionMenuView after click

Tags: android, android-toolbar, highlight, menuitem, actionmenuview

I am using an `ActionMenuView` to display set of filters that the user can select.
After selecting a menu item in the `ActionMenuView`, I want this menu item to be highlighted until another menu item has been selected.

How do I keep the highlight of the menu item once it has been clicked?
The desired result occurs when i put a breakpoint in the `onMenuItemClick` function, it is as follows:

[image: Desired Result]

**EDIT**
Solved the problem, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by modifying the icons of the `ActionMenuView`
using `layer-list` (no highlight by default):

```xml
<!-- drawable/filter_trade_requests_sort_by_creation_date.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_view_menu_base_currency_icon_background">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24px"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

using the following `ActionmenuView`:

```xml
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_trade_requests_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_trade_requests_action_menu_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

After an icon in the `ActionMenuView` is selected, I clear all highlights of the icons in the `ActionMenuView` and set the highlight of the currently selected icon.
The methods are as follows:

```
private fun setFilterIconHighLight(menuItem: MenuItem?, layerId: Int, color: Int) {
    val icon = menuItem?.icon as? LayerDrawable
    val background =
        icon?.findDrawableByLayerId(layerId) as? GradientDrawable
    background?.setColor(color)
}

private fun clearAllIconHighLights(menu: Menu) {
    for (menuItem in menu.iterator()) {
        val icon = menuItem.icon as? LayerDrawable
        val nrOfLayers = icon?.numberOfLayers
        if (nrOfLayers != null && nrOfLayers > 1) {
            for (i in 0 until nrOfLayers) {
                val layer = icon.getDrawable(i)
                if (layer is GradientDrawable) {
                    layer.setColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.WHITE, 0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the drawable listed above, usage would be as follows:

```
private fun updateFilterUI(binding: FragmentTradeRequestsBinding) {
    val actionMenuView = binding.fragmentTradeRequestsActionMenuView.menu
    // Some condition that indicates that we need to highlight
    val menuItem = actionMenuView.findItem(R.id.filter_trade_requests_sort_by_creation_date)
    clearAllIconHighLights(actionMenuView)
    setFilterIconHighLight(
        menuItem,
        R.id.action_view_menu_date_icon_background,
        ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.WHITE, 50)
    )
}
```

A color with an alpha value of 50 is considered a highlight, while a color with an alpha value of 0 is not visible and thus clears the highlight